# disable right click controls in MediaElements.js

Tags: video, save, fullscreen, right-click

Can we disable right click controls in MediaElements.js  like "Save video As" etc when the player is in full screen? if yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

i have written the following java script code

```
var BM = 2; // button middle
var BR = 3; // button right
var msg ="MOUSE RIGHT CLICK IS NOT SUPPORTED ON THIS PAGE";

function mouseDown(e) 
{ 
  try { if (event.button==BM||event.button==BR) {return false;} }  
  catch (e) { if (e.which == BR) {return false;} } 
}
document.oncontextmenu = function() { alert(msg); return false; }
document.onmousedown   = mouseDown;
```

this code works in normal size.... but not working in full screen mode....
i need to disable context menu while mediaelement.js player is in full screen mode......